# EditText Clear Text with click(Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin

Hi i'm using this code when user click on an edittext to clear it.
The Problem is that it doesnt work properly.I mean that i must click my EditText two times for clear it. In first click it opens Keyboard and in second click, it runs my code:
 Here is my code:

```
   var comments = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasComment);
        comments.Click+=delegate
        {
                comments.Text = "";
        };
```

How Can i fix this?

Comment: What class and method contains this code?

Comment: I use it just after SetContentView.So i dont use class

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Xamarin. I know it uses C#, which I also don't know very well. I only develop Android apps in Java. Do you not need a class like you do in a regular C# app? I'll help as much as I can until someone more knowledgeable comes along.

Comment: I'm using an EditText with text Value "Search..." inside. But i want when someone click in it to clear my word. First click open keyboard and second click clears my EditText.Is there any other way i can succeed this?

Comment: it sounds like the editText hasn´t the focus and get it on first click...

Comment: I am not sure about that as I am not developing on xamarin, but I guess you have to call `comments.Focus` at start...

Comment: Which API level are you targeting? I test it on Android 6.0 emulator. Didn't reproduced the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want edit in .cs file you use in onCreate()

```
...
editText.setOnClickListener(this);
...

public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        editText.setText("");
    }
```

---

other way in .cs

```
editText.getText().clear();
```

---

if you want edit axml page, you use placeholder properties. You have wrote already up.

```
android:hint="Enter number"
```

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer with another way. i just added in my edittext

```
android:hint="comments..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

From the [forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/56863/how-can-i-keep-the-default-ontouch-behavior-of-a-edittext-if-i-hook-a-customized-ontouch-handler)

You can use a `onTouchListener` on the `edittext` to clear the data inside it.

```
  myEditText.Click += (sender, eventArgs) => {
// do my business
// Add the line below
(sender as EditText).OnTouchEvent(eventArgs.Event);
};
```

Comment: I get this error
CS1061 'EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Event' and no extension method 'Event' accepting a first argument of type 'EventArgs' could be found

Comment: Go through this link:https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/gestures/detect_a_touch/   to detect a touch event